# validation failed [/author] when Posting to company page linkedin | php

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am trying to post text on my linked in company profile where i am getting following error

> '{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author]","status":403}'

here is the php code which i am using

```
public function linkedInTextPost($accessToken,  $message, $visibility = "PUBLIC")
{
    $post_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?oauth2_access_token=" .$accessToken;
    $request = [
        "author" => "urn:li:organization:6177438",
        "lifecycleState" => "PUBLISHED",
        "specificContent" => [
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent" => [
                "shareCommentary" => [
                    "text" => $message
                ],
                "shareMediaCategory" => "NONE",
            ],
            
        ],
        "visibility" => [
            "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility" => $visibility,
        ]
    ];
    $post = $this->curl($post_url,json_encode($request), "application/json", true);
    return $post;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

i took the reference from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#sample-request-3)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. I haven't requested w_organization_social permission in the app may be due to that its throwing such error.
Any how I requested for permission will update once i get desired result