# Trying to publish messages with my company via an API

Tags: python-requests, linkedin-api

I'm trying to publish messages with my company via an API, but it doesn't work. I can do it directly with my profile on my profile, but I can't do it on behalf of my organization to post to my company page.

**Error received:**
Post creation failed with status code 403: {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/auth
or]","status":403}

**Where does my URN come from:**
https://www.linkedin.com/company/xxxxxxxx/admin/

**Code:**

```
    import requests
    import json
    
    ACCESS_TOKEN = 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
    
    company_urn = 'urn:li:organization:xxxxxxxx'
    author_urn = 'urn:li:person:WMIuTv0paz'
    
    url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts'
    
    headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    
    post_body = {
    "author": f'{company_urn}',
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
    "shareCommentary": {
    "text": "Hello World! This is my first Share on LinkedIn!"
    },
    "shareMediaCategory": "NONE"
    }
    },
    "visibility": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(post_body))
    
    if response.status_code == 201:
    print('Post successfully created!')
    else:
    print(f'Post creation failed with status code {response.status_code}: {response.text}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you don't have [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/increasing-access?view=li-lms-unversioned#what-permissions-are-available) to post on behalf of the organization. In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514747/19813684) `w_organization_social` permission did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response, However, I'm not sure why "w_organization_social" is missing during the token generation process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76720035/19854680

Comment: This permission is available to all developers approved for Community Management API access. Did you [apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/quick-start?view=li-lms-unversioned#step-3-get-started-with-the-community-management-api) to it? [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/increasing-access?view=li-lms-unversioned#what-permissions-are-available)

Also, consider that this permission is restricted to organizations in which the member has one of the following company page roles: `ADMINISTRATOR, DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER, RECRUITING_POSTER`

Comment: If I can create an application, does that mean I've applied for it? I have made the organisation so I have all the rights ?

Comment: Currently, my script only works when I use my own urn from my Linkedin profile

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what else you can do. Try contacting LinkedIn support.

Answer (score 0):

Issue: "**w_organization_social**" Missing during the Token Generation

**Token creation:**
[image]

**Products enabled**
[image]

Comment: Some new information: https://community.n8n.io/t/error-with-linkedin-node-when-posting-as-an-organization/10627/7